# ¿Por qué me muestra esta excepción al intentar abrir un archivo xlsx?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quiero intentar obtener y escribir una cadena en un archivo de `Excel`, pero me muestra una excepción cuando intento ejecutarlo.

El código es este:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
string workbookPath = "c:/Libro1.xlsx";
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet); //en esta instruccion me sale la excepcion
Excel.Range excelCell = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
```

Comment: ¿Que excepcion?

Comment: me aparece una ventana que dice esto:
[Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' en WindowsFormsApplication2.exe

Información adicional: El índice no es válido. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))]

Comment: Parece que en excelSheets no existe un sheet llamado "Sheet1".

Comment: ya lo he resuelto, gracias. 
Tengo excel en español por lo tanto no existe sheet1, lo que hay es hoja 1, ya lo cambie y ya no hay problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun la excepción que te salta:

```
 [Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' en WindowsFormsApplication2.exe 
 Información adicional: El índice no es válido. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))]
```

Parece que en **excelSheets** no existe un sheet llamado *Sheet1*. Posiblemente se llame *Hoja1* y tengas el **excel en español**.